# trust medium in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hosting, web-config, medium-trust

When i try to run my project in trust medium or high it says

[PolicyException: Required permissions cannot be acquired.]

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly

but i'm running all the assemblies in bin only.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load an assembly which requires full trust, for example nhibernate.dll. The location of the assemblies doesn't matter here.